# What is the song at season 3 episode 18 at 19:00 of My Hero Academia when the last 10 students of UA fight all the enemy?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What is the song at season 3 episode 18 of at 19:00 of *My Hero Academia* when the last 10 students of UA fight all the enemy?

Answer (score 1):

My Hero Academia 2018 Original Soundtrack, Disc 2, [Yuga Aoyama](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssrpoeByb6g).